# Get common property using Generic Interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

Sorry I can't really explain in words what I'm tring to do, But..

Say I have the secnario.

```
public class TestClass
{
}

public class TestClass1 : TestClass, TestInterface<ValueClass1>
{
    public ValueClass1 Property { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass2 : TestClass, TestInterface<ValueClass2>
{
    public ValueClass2 Property { get; set; }
}

public interface TestInterface<T> where T : ValueClass
{
    T Property { get; set; }
}

public class ValueClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ValueClass2 : ValueClass
{
}
```

I need to get a value from `Property` from a list of `List<TestClass>` which contains both `TestClass1` and `TestClass2` (and many more), but I cant figure out how to loop though the list and set the `Property` value.

so here is basically what I am trying to do

```
List<TestClass> list = new List<TestClass>();

foreach (var item in list.OfType<????>())
{
    item.Property = PropertyManager.GetProperty(item.Property.Id);
}
```

### Edit:

I have many classes that have a common property, but I need the actual `Type` of that property not the `base Type` (due to other factors such as serialization), and I need to be able to loop though a list of the main base class and access the property.

Like my example above I only need to get the `Id` value from the `Property`.

Currently each class has its own `Property` and I am using `Reflection` to do what I need, I was just looking for a cleaner solution.

### **Edit:**

This is my current implementation

```
public class TestClass
{
}

public class TestClass1 : TestClass
{
    public ValueClass Property { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass2 : TestClass
{
    public ValueClass2 Property { get; set; }
}

public class ValueClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ValueClass2 : ValueClass
{
}
```

and to set the values I have to use reflection

```
List<TestClass> list = new List<TestClass>();

foreach (var item in list.Where(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("Property") != null))
{
    var property = item.GetType().GetProperty("Property");
    property.SetValue(PropertyManager.GetProperty((property.GetValue(item) as ValueClass).Id));
}
```

And the `PropertyManager` is just a `Dictionary` of `ValueClass` types

```
public static ValueClass GetProperty(int id)
{
    if (_properties.Containskey(id))
    {
       return _properties[id];
    }
    return null;
}
```

So what I need is a way to loop though a list of 'TestClass' and populate any derived types that have the `ValueClass` `Property`.

At the moment I see `Reflection` as my only real option.

Comment: Why do you need the `OfType` the list is already of type TestClass which exposed Property?

Comment: @BobVale, sorry, see my edits, I missed the base class in my example.

Comment: In your example, what do you expect to happen if you're trying to set a value of type `ValueClass` to the `Property` property on an instance of type `TypeClass2`.  This will fail at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

These class relationships are a mess and I guarantee you won't get happy with these inheritance and parameter relations. Can you elaborate what you are trying to do?

Anyway, you have access to *Property* and *Id* by:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<TestClass> list = new List<TestClass>();

        foreach (TestClass item in list)
        {
            ValueClass x = item.Property;
            int y = item.Property.Id;
        }
    }
```

In such scenarios it is often good to avoid var at first, to know what type the variables have.

**EDIT**
A quick and not too dirty solution is using **dynamic**.

```
dynamic d = o; // assign the items in your list to a dynamic variable
var somevar = d.Property;    // access any property you expect x to have.
```

**EDIT**
The clean solution would be:
1. Define an interface that has all that you want and need in the loop.
2. Attach the interface to the types that shall implement it.

Comment: While I agree, that really is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: you are right, i was working on the answer and then stopped at this point.

Comment: sorry, I gave a very poor example Of what I am tring to do, I have updated the question, I was missing a whole class, so not all the classes have the `Property` only some of the derived classes, and I only have a list of the base class

Comment: @thomas, what are your thoughts on using `dynamic` vs my current `Reflection` solution, would `dynamic` be faster/safer or is it pretty much the same?

Comment: convenience, less error prone, performance. dynamic is the new escape scenario when class relationships get overly complex (again should not in the normal case). Jon Skeet's "C# in Depth" has on page 415f the longer explanation, which I all subscribe to from my experience. In summary: If nice type safe access is not possible due to language limitations, but dynamic does it, then you face a case to use dynamic in purely managed code.

Comment: @thomas, if I use `dynamic` to set the property in the loop of `TestClass`, I still have to check the property exists or it will throw right? So I would have to use Reflection to check it exists then cast as `dynamic` then populate the `Property`, or am I wrong?

Comment: I assumed you know for sure that each item has the property. If this is not the case, the decision is really a matter of taste. either dynamic with catching the RuntimeBinderException when it does not exist or reflection. Again, the best would be to try getting done with another class design. Define interfaces and try to attach them to your classes. Then you can really filter in your loop with OfType<IMyInterface>() and get just items that exhibit the interface properties.

Comment: @thomas, Well I am tring to find a class/interface design to solve this, but the main proplem is that due to WPF DataTemplates and XmlSerialization the property in the class has to be of its type, I might just stick with the reflection method I am using as its working fine, I was just looking for a nicer alternative, Thaks so much for all the help, if you update your answer showing your Dynamic method looping though a list, I will answer the question as this is the only other way to do what I require :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public virtual ValueClass Property { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass1 : TestClass
{
    private ValueClass property = null;
    public override ValueClass Property
    {
        get
        {
            return property;
        }
        set
        {
            property = (ValueClass)value;
        }
    }
}

public class TestClass2 : TestClass
{
    private ValueClass2 property = null;
    public override ValueClass Property
    {
        get
        {
            return property;
        }
        set
        {
            property = (ValueClass2)value;
        }
    }
}

public class ValueClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ValueClass2 : ValueClass
{
}
```

and:

```
foreach (var item in list)
        {
            item.Property = PropertyManager.GetProperty(item);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, I'm not keen to add the `Property` to the base class, also the `Property` has to be of it `Type` not the base type, this is due to xaml `DataTemplates` and `XmlSerialization` compatability (long story).

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IHasProperty {
   ValueClass PropertyAsValueClass { get;set; }
}

public class TestClass<T> : IHasProperty where T : ValueClass
{
   public T Property {get;set;}

   public ValueClass PropertyAsValueClass {
     get { return this.Property; }
     set { this.Property = value as T; }
   }
}

public class TestClass1 : TestClass<ValueClass>
{
}

public class TestClass2 : TestClass<ValueClass2>
{
}

public class ValueClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ValueClass2 : ValueClass
{
}
```

You could put extra checking in if you wish...

And then

```
var list = new List<IHasProperty>();
foreach (var item in list)
{
    item.PropertyAsValueClass = PropertyManager.GetProperty(item.PropertyAsValueClass.Id);
}
```

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for the answer, but I can't really just add the property to `TestClass`, `TestClass` is used in 1000's of places, I'm starting to think my reflection solution is the only solution :(

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Can you create a new intermediate class that inherits from testclass and make TestClass1 and TestClass2 inherit from that?

Comment: I also thought of that but it messes up the xml serilization, I was hoping to solve this on the class level, but it looks like I will just have to stick with the Reflection solution as it works fine at the moment, but I was just hoping there a cleaner way to do this, thanks for you answers :)

Comment: What about just implementing the interface in each class and then using `list.OfType<IHasProperty>()`